# How to get data from Excel and merge it into Word using MailMerge?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Trying to get data from Excel and merge it into Word using MailMerge (just like how it is done in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FWc7EvlfjQ)).
However, fields aren't getting updated after running this code. VBA isn't throwing any error so looks like code is fine. Can you please help?

```
Sub getdata()
Dim numRecord As Integer
Dim myName As String

myName = InputBox("Enter the field name and relax!")
Set dsMain = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource
If dsMain.FindRecord(FindText:=myName, Field:="Fields") = True Then
    numRecord = dsMain.ActiveRecord
End If
End Sub
```

Note: Data in Excel looks like this:

```
Fields  First Layer    Second Layer
 CC         5              3
```

So when someone enters CC in Input box I want first_layer and Second_layer fields in word to get updated to 5 and 3 respectiely.

Comment: The description of the video has working example files. Does those work for you?

Comment: No Hassan, sadly they dont work

Comment: What version of MS Office you have?

Comment: It is 2016 version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the mailmerge from Word, you don't actually need any VBA for this - it can all be done with a SKIPIF field. For example the following field code does the same as the macro in the video is supposed to:

{SKIPIF{FILLIN "Name to merge" \o}<> {MERGEFIELD Name}}

or:

{SKIPIF{FILLIN "Name to merge" \o}<> «Name»}

**Note:** The field brace pairs (i.e. '{ }') for the above example are all created in the document itself, via Ctrl-F9 (Cmd-F9 on a Mac or, if you’re using a laptop, you might need to use Ctrl-Fn-F9); you can't simply type them or copy & paste them from this message. Nor is it practical to add them via any of the standard Word dialogues. Likewise, the chevrons (i.e. '« »') are part of the actual mergefields - which you can insert from the 'Insert Merge Field' dropdown (i.e. you can't type or copy & paste them from this message, either). The spaces represented in the field constructions are all required.