# How to use mail merge and also {ASK} Fields.Update in same document

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

I have a Word macro which opens a Word document (Letter template) which contains several merge fields tied to an Excel spreadsheet.  I got that done with help from this article: [How to get data from Excel and merge it into Word using MailMerge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58007398).

The spreadsheet contains static information about the letter **sender**. When this letter template opens, I get a prompt (yes/No) to run the merge. Great. I click yes and I get another popup listing some other merge fields not found in the spreadsheet.  These other merge fields exist in the template in this form:
{ASK Name "Type Name of Addressee" * MERGEFORMAT}{REF Name}

There are several of those in the template, to build the addressee's area (name, address, city, etc.).

Basically, I need to first run the merge from Excel to build the letter with **sender** information and then I need to prompt the user for the other addressee information, separately through the {ASK} merge fields. I can't figure out how to run the two merges (one from Excel and the other one from the {ASK} fields without getting interrupted by Word because the {ASK} fields don't exist in the Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: FYI generally when asking questions about your code it's a good idea to include it in your post, otherwise it's likely your question will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

«I get another popup listing some other merge fields not found in the spreadsheet. These other merge fields exist in the template in this form: {ASK Name "Type Name of Addressee" * MERGEFORMAT}{REF Name}»

If you really are getting a warning about "other merge fields not found in the spreadsheet", that has nothing to do with your ASK & REF fields and your document really does have MERGEFIELDs pointing to data fields that don't exist in the workbook. You need to fix that.

Moreover, instead of:

{ASK Name "Type Name of Addressee" * MERGEFORMAT}{REF Name}

you could use:

{FILLIN "Type Name of Addressee"}

Comment: I replaced all the {ASK} fields with {FILLIN} and it's working perfectly now.  Thanks a whole bunch!